# Access - Link to Outlook Contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-access

in Access I had a linked table sourcing from Outlook contacts, which I then used for further data elaboration.
Since some weeks I get "unable to find field" error.
I then tried to:

- create a new linked table from scratch but I get error *An error occurred trying to link to file 'Contacts'. The link was not created*
- create a new imported (not linked) table but I get error *The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the Object ". Make sure the Object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If " is not a local Object check your network connection or contact the server administrator.*

Has something been changed from Outlook side?
What could be the reason for these errors?

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of Outlook client, if you are using Exchange account,it is suggested to [turn off your cache mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-on-cached-exchange-mode-7885af08-9a60-4ec3-850a-e221c1ed0c1c) and see if the issue has any difference. Besides, I also found some other information related to Import or link to contacts from an Outlook address book, please check https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-link-to-contacts-from-an-outlook-address-book-e2ff9669-5b95-483e-be8d-83590c2085a3

Comment: thanks, but company policy doesn't allow to turn off cache mode. Regarding second link there isn't unfortunately any useful additional information about this issue...